# SharedPreferences used to display text, not showing

Tags: android, textview, android-sqlite, sharedpreferences, settext

I am trying to set User text in my Navigation drawer. For two values name and course i call string method from database class and store it in a string. The other two values id and email i get it from the user and store it. I use SharedPreferences to pass the values. Then in my navigation activity inside onCreate i get the values then set it to the appropriate textview. But nothing shows up. It remains empty after registering. What am i doing wrong here?

I should also mention that i don't start navigation activity after registration. It's Register->Login->Dashboard->Navigation. So its the 4th activity to which i am passing the values. 
I have used the Navigation activity provided by Google and created the settext inside onCreate, still not getting the desired output.

Navigation:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.n);
        txtsid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.s);
        txtcourse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.c);
        txtemail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.e);

        SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);

            String name = myPrefs.getString("name", "null");
            String course = myPrefs.getString("course", "null");
            String sid = myPrefs.getString("sid", "null");
            String email = myPrefs.getString("email", "null");

            if (myPrefs.contains("name")) txtName.setText(name);
            if (myPrefs.contains("course")) txtcourse.setText(course);
            if (myPrefs.contains("sid")) txtsid.setText(sid);
            if (myPrefs.contains("email")) txtemail.setText(email);


    }
```

Register:

```
buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (validate()) {
                    String Email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
                    String SID = editTextSID.getText().toString();
                    String Password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    //Check in the database is there any user associated with  this email

                    if (!sqliteHelper.ifUserRegistered(SID) && sqliteHelper.ifUserExists(SID) && !sqliteHelper.isEmailExists(Email)) {

                        sqliteHelper.registerUser(new User(null, Email, SID, Password));
                        Snackbar.make(buttonRegister, "User created successfully! Please Login ", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        String name = sqliteHelper.getUserNameFromSID(SID);
                        String course = sqliteHelper.getUserCourseFromSID(SID);
                        SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("SharedPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();
                        editor.putString("name", name);
                        editor.putString("course", course);
                        editor.putString("sid", SID);
                        editor.putString("email", Email);
                        editor.commit();

                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                finish();
                            }
                        }, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
```

My textviews are under nav_header.xml with just layout height and width attribute, and this is included in the main navigation.xml under the headerlayout attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is caused by an incorrect filename.

In your **Register**, you used `getSharedPreferences("SharedPref", MODE_PRIVATE);` Basically, your SharedPreference file is named **SharedPref**.

However, in **Navigation**, you used `getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);` Basically, you're fetching a SharedPreference file named **myPrefs**.

So you're simply saving to one file, but trying to fetch that data from another file.

Therefore, in your **Navigation**, when you coded your `setText()` in this way:

```
if (myPrefs.contains("name")) txtName.setText(name);
if (myPrefs.contains("course")) txtcourse.setText(course);
if (myPrefs.contains("sid")) txtsid.setText(sid);
if (myPrefs.contains("email")) txtemail.setText(email);
```

There's no way the `myPrefs` file will contain those names, so it'll always fail the check and `setText()` is never called.

So the fix for this is simply to use the same filename.

In **Navigation** replace:

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

with:

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("SharedPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

try to replace your code,

```
txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.n);
        txtsid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.s);
        txtcourse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.c);
        txtemail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.e);
```

with

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view); 
View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0); 
txtName  = (TextView)  headerView.findViewById(R.id.n);
txtsid = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.s);
txtcourse = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.c);
txtemail = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.e);
```